# Perform a SQL query search based on one or both user inputs and populate a grid view with the results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search, gridview

I am working on a small search form that has two text fields: One that allows users to search for a job list (which is basically a wish list--don't know why they want to call it a "job list" but whatever) by entering in part of or a full email address or someone's first and/or last name (This textbox is called SearchName). This field is required and if it is blank when the user hits "Search," an error message appears telling them so. The second textbox is optional, and it allows users to enter in a city or a state to help narrow their search down even more (this textbox is called SearchLocation).

I have a function (called getJobLists()) that is used by the search button to get results.

As it is right now, the part of the function that returns results based on what is entered into the SearchName field works perfectly. However, I cannot get any results for SearchLocation. When I enter a valid email or name into SearchName, then enter a valid city or state into SearchLocation, I get no results. However, if I enter in anything invalid (i.e. a city that is not associated with the entered email or name) the "no results found" message does appear.

I have tested both SQL queries in my search function in SQL Server Management Studio and they do work perfectly.

I have a try-catch inside the search function, but no error is being shown, not even in the console.

This is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // CHECK IF THE WISHLIST SEARCH ENABLED
        StoreSettingsManager settings = AbleContext.Current.Store.Settings;
        if (!settings.WishlistSearchEnabled)
        {
            Response.Redirect(AbleCommerce.Code.NavigationHelper.GetHomeUrl());
            return;
        }
    }
    protected void getJobLists()
    {
       try 
       { 
           if (SearchName.Text != "")
           {//if SearchName.Text is not blank
               if (SearchLocation.Text != "")
               {//check to see if SearchLocation.Text is not blank either
                   string sqlSelect = "SELECT (FirstName +' '+ LastName) AS 'FullName', UserName,  (Address1 + ', ' +City + ', ' + Province) AS 'Address' FROM ac_Users INNER JOIN ac_Wishlists ON ac_Wishlists.UserId = ac_Users.UserId INNER JOIN ac_Addresses ON ac_Addresses.UserId = ac_Wishlists.UserId WHERE IsBilling ='true' AND (UserName LIKE '%'+@UserName+'%' OR (FirstName + LastName) LIKE '%'+@UserName+'%') AND ((City + Province) LIKE '%'+@Location+'%')";

                    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, cn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", String.Format("%{0}%", SearchName.Text));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", String.Format("%{0}%", SearchLocation.Text));
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cn.Open();

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                        DataTable jobsListsTbl = ds.Tables.Add("jobsListsTbl");

                        jobsListsTbl.Columns.Add("User", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        jobsListsTbl.Columns.Add("PrimaryAddress", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                DataRow dr = jobsListsTbl.NewRow();

                                dr["User"] = reader["Name"];
                                dr["PrimaryAddress"] = reader["Address"];
                                jobsListsTbl.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }         
                        WishlistGrid.DataSource = ds;
                        WishlistGrid.DataMember = "jobsListsTbl";
                        WishlistGrid.DataBind();
                    }

               }//end of if(SearchLocation.Text !='')
               else
               {//if SearchLocation.Text is blank, then go with this code instead
                   string sqlSelect2 = "SELECT (FirstName +' '+ LastName) AS 'FullName', UserName,  (Address1 + ', ' +City + ', ' + Province) AS 'Address' FROM ac_Users INNER JOIN ac_Wishlists ON ac_Wishlists.UserId = ac_Users.UserId INNER JOIN ac_Addresses ON ac_Addresses.UserId = ac_Wishlists.UserId WHERE IsBilling ='true' AND (UserName LIKE '%'+@UserName+'%' OR (FirstName + LastName) LIKE '%'+@UserName+'%')";

                   using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
                   {
                       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect2, cn);
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", String.Format("%{0}%", SearchName.Text));

                       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                       cn.Open();

                       DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                       DataTable jobsListsTbl2 = ds.Tables.Add("jobsListsTbl2");

                       jobsListsTbl2.Columns.Add("User", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                       jobsListsTbl2.Columns.Add("PrimaryAddress", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                       using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                       {
                           while (reader.Read())
                           {
                               DataRow dr = jobsListsTbl2.NewRow();

                               dr["User"] = reader["UserName"];
                               dr["PrimaryAddress"] = reader["Address"];
                               jobsListsTbl2.Rows.Add(dr);
                           }
                       }
                       WishlistGrid.DataSource = ds;
                       WishlistGrid.DataMember = "jobsListsTbl2";
                       WishlistGrid.DataBind();
                   }

               }//end if SearchLocation.Text is empty
            }//end of if SearchName.Text !==''   

           }
           catch (Exception x)
           {
               errors5.Text += "ERROR: " + x.Message.ToString() + "<br />";
           }
    }
    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WishlistGrid.Visible = true;
        getJobLists();
    }
```

And this is the designer code for the search form (Note: the NavigateUrl is not set for the hyperlink yet. I will set it once everything is displaying properly for the search results):

```
<div id="findWishlistPage" class="mainContentWrapper">
<div class="section">
<div class="introDiv">
    <div class="pageHeader">
        <h1>Find a Job List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <asp:label id="errors" runat="server" text=""></asp:label>
        <asp:label id="errors2" runat="server" text=""></asp:label>
        <asp:label id="errors3" runat="server" text=""></asp:label>
        <asp:label id="errors4" runat="server" text=""></asp:label>
        <asp:label id="errors5" runat="server" text=""></asp:label>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Searchajax" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DefaultButton="SearchButton">
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                    <table class="inputForm">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="rowHeader">
                                <asp:Label ID="SearchNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Name or E-mail:" AssociatedControlID="SearchName" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Textbox id="SearchName" runat="server" onfocus="this.select()" Width="200px" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Textbox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SearchNameValdiator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SearchName"
                                     Text="*" ErrorMessage="Name or email address is required." EnableViewState="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="rowHeader">
                                <asp:Label ID="SearchLocationLabel" runat="server" Text="City or State (optional):" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox id="SearchLocation" runat="server" onfocus="this.select()" Width="140px" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="SearchButton" runat="server" CssClass="button linkButton" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" EnableViewState="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br />
                    <asp:GridView ID="WishlistGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="true" 
                        SkinID="PagedList" Visible="false" EnableViewState="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="wishlistName" />
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="wishlistName" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="WishlistLink" runat="server" >
                                        <%#Eval("User")%>
                                    </asp:HyperLink>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="wishlistLocation" />
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="wishlistLocation" />
                                <ItemTemplate> 
                                    <asp:Label ID="Location" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PrimaryAddress")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    <%--'<%#GetLocation(Eval("User.PrimaryAddress"))%>'--%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <asp:Localize ID="EmptySearchResult" runat="server" Text="There were no job lists matching your search criteria."></asp:Localize>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please try to narrow down your question. In my opinion it is too long. +1 for the effort

Comment: I applaud your effort in typing that out, but tl;dr

Comment: Okay, I shortened it. I hope everything is still clear...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally solved the issue. Apparently, it was a variable naming issue I kept overlooking. But now it all works okay! :)